# using space in path for copying files using batch script

Tags: windows, linux, shell, batch-file

I want to copy all the *.jar files to another directory  i wrote the below script

```
echo Enter path to ILM_HOME: 
set /p ILM_HOME=

echo Deployment in progress
copy  WEB-INF/lib/*.jar "%ILM_HOME%"/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
```

I use `C:\Documents and Settings\asimon\Desktop\test` as my input

It gives me `syntax of the command is incorrect`

I think the problem is `Documents and Settings` I even put `"%ILM_HOME%"` and I don't need `c:\Docume~1\asimon\Desktop\test` any other solution?

**Update**

This is working

```
@echo off
echo

echo Enter path to ILM_HOME: 
set /p ILM_HOME=

IF EXIST "%ILM_HOME%\stopApplimation.bat" (

echo Deployment in progress
xcopy WEB-INF\lib\*.jar "%ILM_HOME%\webapp\WEB-INF\lib"

CALL "%ILM_HOME%\stopApplimation.bat"

CALL "%ILM_HOME%\startApplimation.bat"

) ELSE (
echo %ILM_HOME% path is incorrect.
)
```

also any linux solution is also helpfull with .sh for the below 2 statements

```
"%ILM_HOME%/stopApplimation.bat"
"%ILM_HOME%/startApplimation.bat"
```

for linux, how can i replace the above 2 statements?

```
$ILM_HOME/stopApplimation.sh
$ILM_HOME/startApplimation.sh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try
`xcopy  WEB-INF\lib\*.jar "%ILM_HOME%\webapp\WEB-INF\lib"`?

**EDITED:**
In your batch use `CALL "%ILM_HOME%\stopApplimation.bat"`

Comment: @Macro: Thanks it helped, also 1 more help, how can i start another batch script? i updated my question with 2 more statements.

Comment: @Macro: The last 2 lines gives me error `'"C:\534HF2\webapp\csm\stopApplimation.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or
 external command,
operable program or batch file.
'"C:\534HF2\webapp\csm\startApplimation.bat"' is not recognized as an internal o
r external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: are you sure those files exist in that path and that they really are batches files?

Comment: @Macro: Thanks i checked whether the batch file exists then it performs the operations. it works now, also do you have any idea how to run `.sh` in linux?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: I think you have to edit attributes oh those files using `chmod ug+x your_sh_file` and then you can use `./your_sh_file` to run it